# how do deploy CodeIgniter application from gitHub

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am having some challenges deploying from Amazon Web Services AWS Code Deploy from a github repository.

The repository houses a web application using the codeigniter framework.

When deploying to an EC2 instance using the AWS Code Deploy, it would start the deployment process and then fail. No error message was provided.

Can anyone provide some further guides on how to deploy codeigniter apps to AWS without using FTP.

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: Are you deploying to stand alone ec2 or elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Ec2 for now but would like to know if there is a difference if I wanted to scale to elastic beanstalk

Comment: I would move to elastic beanstalk sooner and do your for deploy to the EB application. It has worked very well for me so far. Git deploy to ec2 stand alone has been a head ache